# Does Async process complete as expected even when component is destroyed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, closures, lexical-scope

I have a pop up modal, when the user clicks on submit in the modal, it goes to my database and saves some data there. The modal is closed after that. 
However, since it is a modal, the user is able to close it via ESC button. So I want to ensure even if the user pressed ESC, the async still completes without getting cut off in the middle.

For example.

```
// from my modal component
onSubmit() {
    this.databaseService.saveToDatabase(data)
        .first()
        .subscribe(result => {
            console.log('complete')
            closeModal();
        }, error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('modal Desstroyed')
}
```

For the above example, if I pressed esc as soon as I hit submit, I see from the console

```
modal Destroyed

complete
```

This suggests that my async call finish as expected which is good. I found it weird though..... why didnt Angular 2 hang on to the component until the async process completes. 
How can my onSubmit function finish even though the component has been destroyed (assuming that is what happens when ngOnDestry() gets called). In another language such as Swift, the view controller does not get destroyed unless all the process is completed (Unless you specify it to get destroyed regardless)

Another example that I have not tested out... what if the async call is much longer like the following. Will I still reach '2nd stage complete' if I close the modal immediately upon pressing submit button

```
// from my modal component
onSubmit() {
    this.databaseService.saveToDatabase(data)
        .first()
        .subscribe(result => {
            console.log('complete 1st stage')
            this.databaseService.saveToDatabase(reult)
                .first()
                .subscribe(result => {
                    console.log('2nd stage complete')
                    closeModal();
                })
        })
}
```

Comment: `onSubmit` finishes immediately, long before the request is complete. It is a fire and forget function as you have defined it. This happens regardless of whether or not you close the modal. On submit passes a closure to subscribe. Learn about closures, learn about lexical scoping, learn about JavaScript. You cannot understand TypeScript if you do not understand JavaScript. Period.

Answer (score 0):

I won't talk about JS asynchronicity as it has been covered all around Stack Overflow and many tutorial site, etc. I'll just talk about Observables and subscription management.

First thing to know is "it depends". It depends on the way your `Observable` is created, and the way you manage your subscription.

when you create an Observable with `Observable.create` you define what to do when you unsubscribe. In this example, the interval is stopped when you unsubscribe :

```
let foo = Observable.create((observer)=>{
  // this is called when an observer subscribe to this Observable
  let interval = setInterval(()=>{
    observer.next("foo");
  });
  // returns what to do on unsubscribe...
  return ()=>{
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
});
let sub = foo.subscribe(data=>console.log(data));
window.setTimeout(()=>sub.unsubscribe(),1000); // passed 1000ms, unsubscribe and cancel the interval...
```

For example, whit angular's `Http` service, an http Request is cancelled when you unsubscribe to it.

While you don't unsubscribe from your `Observable` and it does not `complete`, it is still running, wether component is destroyed or not.

Note that it is a good practice to [avoid multiple subscriptions](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87#.njo42811v), because when you manage your subscriptions imperatively, you don't get the benefits from using RxJS. So it is better to use the available operators to control the flow of your events.